# AWS S3 Javascript in the browser error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying out the AWS Javascript SDK, I wrote a simple code based on the examples to get the list of files in a bucket. But I keep getting `NetworkingError: Network Failure`, and can't  find any references to this error in the docs.

I also get the same error when I try a `getObject`.

My code:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId : 'myaccesskey',
    secretAccessKey : 'mysecretkey'
});
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

function list(){
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'}});
      bucket.listObjects(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' items from S3';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('objects').innerHTML +=
                   '<li>' + data.Contents[i].Key + '</li>';
             }
        }
      });
}
```

I configured CORS to accept GET from all locations.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The list of regions and endpoints can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Am using your same code. Please check the below version with your code ;

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc4.min.js"></script>
```

Again, please double check the region. If you still receive a Network Failure error, please give me the script you're using and the bucket name so I can check on my end.

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is attempting to access the bucket in the region you've configured (`'us-west-2'`). A networking error with S3 usually means that your bucket does not exist in the region you've configured (it is trying to connect to `myBucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`).

Is that where your bucket is? If you did not select a region when you created your bucket, it is probably in the "US Standard" region, which maps to `'us-east-1'` in the SDK.